# Update-in nested map

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure and I've been staring at this for some time, I'm sure there's something basic I just don't see.  I want to conj two sets, but they're nested, example:

```
(def foo {:b #{:test}})
(def bar {:a {:b #{:ab}} :c :d})
```

I tried:

```
=>(update-in bar [:a :b] conj (:b foo) )
{:a {:b #{#{:test} :ab}}, :c :d}
```

I guess that makes sense, but what I wanted was {:a {:b #{:test :ab}}, :c :d}

I just can't seem how to get either #{:test} out of the set to conj it, or to properly access :b as a set given the update-in syntax.

Any help is enormously appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `into` instead of `conj`:

```
(update-in bar [:a :b] into (:b foo))
;= {:a {:b #{:test :ab}}, :c :d}
```

Comment: `clojure.set/union` would also work, though it may have different performance characteristics (depending on size and concrete type of sets involved).